# What are some good resources for aws security? Like a security checklist for different services

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'll be working on a project to improve the security of a client's aws infrastructure soon. While I know the basics (cleared solutions architect associate) I'm not great at all things aws security.
It would be great if you kind folks directed me to some good resources that I can refer to that would help create a sound plan to evaluate the client's cloud security and  improve their security posture on aws.
Something like a checklist for different services. Like for example enabling log validation on your cloud trail logs for instance.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some places to visit:

- [Cloud Security – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/security/)
- [AWS Whitepapers & Guides](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/?whitepapers-main.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&whitepapers-main.sort-order=desc)
- [Amazon Web Services: Overview of Security Processes](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-security-whitepaper.pdf)
- [Whitepaper | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tag/whitepaper/)